# History of User privileges held

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, audit

In Oracle 12c or 11g, is it possible to fetch the history of user privileges held by a schema? Say from last two months, I might have granted different roles and privileges. I can get the current privileges the schema holds, but is it possible to know the privileges I previously granted?

Edit:
I have standard auditing enabled 'DB'. FGA is not enabled.

Comment: Do you have auditing enabled for it?

Comment: Yes standard auditing

Answer (score 2):

Well there is no official method of getting the list of previous privileges list of a user or a role. But my suggestion would be doing a `Fine-grained` auditing on the role granted to the user. Or you can do standard auditing on the role by issuing `audit <role_name>;` . Here please note that if you are going to audit DBA or SYSDBA roles then set `audit_sys_operations` parameter to `TRUE`. Thank you.